# Python remove part of the string from column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, expression

Hi I am working on python. I created a dataframe from a csv file. One column "name" which is a text column, has inside in different places this pattern ' (some_number + %)',
example:

*"145 wefwignweon **(100%)**, 1rberbebe **(50%)**, vwrbvwrbe **(100%)**, 140 ewggrrwrg"*

I need to delete from this column where says: ' (100%)', '(100%), '(50%')
In other columns are different percentage values

```
import pandas as pd

path_to_dir="/Users/user/Documents/file/"
name='owner.csv'
df_owner = pd.read_csv(path_to_dir+name, encoding='windows-1252') 
#df_owner["name"] =  df_owner["name"] drop where says => (' (@some_number%)')
```

How I can create like a kind of regular expression to drop where find this kind of values something like this?
delete where says '( some_number + %)' in name column from df_owner dataframe

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regular expression  `\(\d+%\)`:

```
df = df[~df['name'].str.contains(r' \(\d+%\)', regex=True)]
```

Comment: OP wants the pattern removed. Your answer seems to remove the entire row of whenever the pattern is found. That is, they want `"145 wefwignweon (100%), 1rberbebe (50%), vwrbvwrbe (100%), 140 ewggrrwrg"` replaced with `"145 wefwignweon , 1rberbebe , vwrbvwrbe ), 140 ewggrrwrg"`.

Comment: This showing me the columns with (100%) , (50%)

Comment: Will you please provide an actual printout of your dataframe, or a portion thereof? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

[Capture all numbers up to three digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53196561/capture-all-numbers-up-to-three-digits) gives  `r'\d{1,3}'`

But you also seem to want the parentheses, and they and the percentage sign have to be escaped, so that will be `r'\(\d{1,3}\)\%'`. You can then replace occurrences of that regex with the null string with `lambda x: re.sub(r'\(\d{1,3}\)\%', '', x)`. You also might want to add the leading space to the regex.

Comment: Hi , i see these values:
1450 fwegwrherheheh
4556 gwregerh 
4804 nifwengiwn
should be 1450 fwegwrherheheh
4556 gwregerh
4804 nifwengiwn